# simplifying multiline code

Tags: tikz-pgf

Can the following code be simplified as a one line code

```
    \documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape]
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (5.5,0) node [black, xshift=.3cm, yshift=0cm] {$t$};
\draw [thick,-latex](0,-2) -- (0,2.5) node [black, xshift=0cm, yshift=.3cm] {$lt$};
\draw [very thick, blue] (.6,0) +(-45:.5cm) -- +(135:.5cm) node [pos=0,circle, draw, blue, fill=blue, scale=0.4]{}  node [pos=1,circle, draw, blue, fill=blue, scale=0.4]{};
\draw [very thick, blue] (1.306,0) +(-135:.5cm) -- +(45:.5cm) node [pos=0,circle, draw, blue, fill=blue, scale=0.4]{}  node [pos=1,circle, draw, blue, fill=blue, scale=0.4]{};
\draw [very thick, blue] (2.01,0) +(-45:.5cm) -- +(135:.5cm) node [pos=0,circle, draw, blue, fill=blue, scale=0.4]{}  node [pos=1,circle, draw, blue, fill=blue, scale=0.4]{};
\draw [very thick, blue] (2.72,0) +(-135:.5cm) -- +(45:.5cm) node [pos=0,circle, draw, blue, fill=blue, scale=0.4]{}  node [pos=1,circle, draw, blue, fill=blue, scale=0.4]{};
\draw [very thick, blue] (3.426,0) +(-45:.5cm) -- +(135:.5cm) node [pos=0,circle, draw, blue, fill=blue, scale=0.4]{}  node [pos=1,circle, draw, blue, fill=blue, scale=0.4]{};
\draw [very thick, blue] (4.132,0) +(-135:.5cm) -- +(45:.5cm) node [pos=0,circle, draw, blue, fill=blue, scale=0.4]{}  node [pos=1,circle, draw, blue, fill=blue, scale=0.4]{};
\draw [very thick, blue] (4.84,0) +(-45:.5cm) -- +(135:.5cm) node [pos=0,circle, draw, blue, fill=blue, scale=0.4]{}  node [pos=1,circle, draw, blue, fill=blue, scale=0.4]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think Ti*k*Z doesn't care for new line characters, so you could put everything into a single line... You could just use one `\draw` instance for each option combination. You could define styles for commonly used option combinations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit 2**
@marmot's comment inspired an even shorter solution, no `scope` needed anymore. And I only just noticed that you did not draw the first sample (at `x=0`) so I also removed that.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (5.5,0) node [black, xshift=.3cm, yshift=0cm] {$t$};
    \draw [thick,-latex](0,-2) -- (0,2.5) node [black, xshift=0cm, yshift=.3cm] {$lt$};
    \draw[very thick,blue] plot[mark=*,samples at={1,3,...,15}] ({sqrt(2)/4*\x},{sqrt(2)/4*sin(90*\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Edit**
An alternative without using `pgfplots`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (5.5,0) node [black, xshift=.3cm, yshift=0cm] {$t$};
    \draw [thick,-latex](0,-2) -- (0,2.5) node [black, xshift=0cm, yshift=.3cm] {$lt$};
    \begin{scope}[x=0.3536cm,y=0.3536cm]
        \draw[very thick,blue] plot[mark=*] coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (3,-1) (5,1) (7,-1) (9,1) (11,-1) (13,1) (15,-1)};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

This comes fairly close:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ymin = -2,
        ymax= 2.5,
        axis equal,
        axis lines=middle,
        ticks=none,
        xmax = 5.5,
        xlabel = \( t \),
        ylabel = \( lt \)
    ]
        \addplot+[
            very thick,
            x filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{#1*0.3536}\pgfmathresult},
            y filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{#1*0.3536}\pgfmathresult}] 
            coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (3,-1) (5,1) (7,-1) (9,1) (11,-1) (13,1) (15,-1)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can this code be applied with the draw command, instead of the (addplot command within axis environment).

Comment: @Hany Sure! See edit.

Comment: It is even shorter if you don't load pgfplots in your second example ;-) And `\draw[very thick,blue] plot[mark=*,variable=\x,samples at={0,1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15}] 
  (\x,{sin(90*\x)});` would be even shorter. (+1 BTW)

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\newcounter{slope}
\newcounter{altslope}
\setcounter{slope}{-45}
\setcounter{altslope}{135}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape]
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (5.5,0) node [black, xshift=.3cm, yshift=0cm] {$t$};
\draw [thick,-latex](0,-2) -- (0,2.5) node [black, xshift=0cm, yshift=.3cm] {$lt$};
\foreach\x in{1,...,7}{%
  \draw [very thick, red] (-.1+.7071*\x,0) +(\theslope:.5cm) -- +(\thealtslope:.5cm) node [pos=0,circle, draw, blue, fill=blue, scale=0.4]{}  node [pos=1,circle, draw, blue, fill=blue, scale=0.4]{};
  \ifnum\theslope<-90\relax\addtocounter{slope}{90}\else%
    \addtocounter{slope}{-90}\fi%
  \ifnum\thealtslope<90\relax\addtocounter{altslope}{90}\else%
    \addtocounter{altslope}{-90}\fi%
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]